# Pepper leaves are dry

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, leaves, peppers

I live in Israel and this pepper plant leaves are falling out (but little ones are growing back) [image]

[image]

would appreciate any help!

Comment: It's hard to tell, but maybe your plant is over watered?

Comment: I see edema which is typically from over watering. I would recommend removing the diseased leaves and cutting back on water. Peppers prefer to be a little on the dry side from time to time. Also, I'm not sure of your climate, but the northern hemisphere is entering winter and peppers do not thrive in winter.

Comment: Did you changes something? Overwatering + sun burns?

Comment: @user1469762: peppers survives winter in northern hemisphere, Just try it (just move on a sheltered place, or cover the plants. Do no worry if they lose all leaves, they will growth back (and still in winter, it is just initial shock).